# Search for Substring in several fields with MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

I am so sorry, but after one day researching and trying all different combinations and npm packages, I am still not sure how to deal with the following task.

Setup:

- MongoDB 2.6
- Node.JS with Mongoose 4

I have a schema like so:

```
var trackingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  tracking_number: String,
  zip_code: String,
  courier: String,
  user_id: Number,
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, 
  international_shipment: { type: Boolean, default: false }, 
  delivery_info: { 
    recipient: String, 
    street: String, 
    city: String
  }
});
```

Now user gives me a search string, a rather an array of strings, which will be *substrings* of what I want to search:

```
var search = ['15323', 'julian', 'administ'];
```

Now I want to find those documents, where any of the fields `tracking_number`, `zip_code`, or these fields in `delivery_info` contain my search elements.

How should I do that? I get that there are indexes, but I probably need a compound index, or maybe a text index? And for search, I then can use `RegEx`, or the `$text $search` syntax?

The problem is that I have several strings to look for (my `search`), and several fields to look in. And due to one of those aspects, every approach failed for me at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I came up with this.

My schema now has an extra field `search` with an array of all my searchable fields:

```
var trackingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    search: [String]
});
```

With a pre-save hook, I populate this field:

```
trackingSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

  this.search = [ this.tracking_number ];

  var searchIfAvailable = [
    this.zip_code,
    this.delivery_info.recipient,
    this.delivery_info.street,
    this.delivery_info.city
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < searchIfAvailable.length; i++) {
    if (!validator.isNull(searchIfAvailable[i])) {
      this.search.push(searchIfAvailable[i].toLowerCase());
    }
  }

  next();
});
```

In the hope of improving performance, I also index that field (also the `user_id` as I limit search results by that):

```
trackingSchema.index({ search: 1 });
trackingSchema.index({ user_id: 1 });
```

Now, when searching I first list all substrings I want to look for in an array:

```
var andArray = [];
var searchTerms = searchRequest.split(" ");
searchTerms.forEach(function(searchTerm) {
  andArray.push({
    search: { $regex: searchTerm, $options: 'i'
    }
  });
});
```

I use this array in my `find()` and chain it with an `$and`:

```
  Tracking.
    find({ $and: andArray }).
      where('user_id').equals(userId).
      limit(pageSize).
      skip(pageSize * page).
      exec(function(err, docs) {
         // hooray!
      });
```

This works.

Comment: If all indexes are set properly, this is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Your use case is a good fit for [text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes-text/).

Define a text index on your schema over the searchable fields:

```
trackingSchema.index({
    tracking_number: 'text',
    zip_code: 'text',
    'delivery_info.recipient': 'text',
    'delivery_info.street': 'text',
    'delivery_info.city': 'text'
}, {name: 'search'});
```

Join your search terms into a single string and execute the search using the [`$text`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) query operator:

```
var search = ['15232', 'julian'];
Test.find({$text: {$search: search.join(' ')}}, function(err, docs) {...});
```

Even though this passes all your search values as a single string, this still performs a logical OR search of the values.

Comment: Yes, I though that text search would be a good fit for that. Two questions: **First**: If I do `search.join(' ')` it will search for the occurrence of `'15232 julian'` in my search fields, not for the occurrence of `'15232'` **and** `'julian'`, or will it? Because I want to search for each search string individually. **Second**: Would this be faster than my solution with the normal index (in my answer).

Comment: @Julian See updated answer. This will likely have better performance than your solution as the use of an index with your regex is [limited](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) as it isn't anchored to the start of the string.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for the clarification! Is there a way to enforce a logical **and** for all the search strings?

Comment: Actually, after working more with it, it turns out that `text-search` **is not a good fit**. As described in the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-text/#text-search), text-search _matches on the complete stemmed words. For example, if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match the document._ Therefore, a substring will never be found.

Comment: @Julian Ok, your example search terms in your question appear to be whole words, so that's what this answer is based on.

Comment: Ah okay! Understood.

Answer (score 1):

Why just dont try

```
var trackingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  tracking_number: String,
  zip_code: String,
  courier: String,
  user_id: Number,
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, 
  international_shipment: { type: Boolean, default: false }, 
  delivery_info: { 
    recipient: String, 
    street: String, 
    city: String
  }
});
var Tracking = mongoose.model('Tracking', trackingSchema );

var search = [ "word1", "word2", ...]
var results = []
for(var i=0; i<search.length; i++){
    Tracking.find({$or : [
      { tracking_number : search[i]}, 
      {zip_code: search[i]}, 
      {courier: search[i]}, 
      {delivery_info.recipient: search[i]}, 
      {delivery_info.street: search[i]}, 
      {delivery_info.city: search[i]}] 
    }).map(function(tracking){
    //it will push every unique result to variable results
    if(results.indexOf(tracking)<0) results.push(tracking);
    });
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought moving the logic to the database would be better. Hm.

Comment: It mostly depends on what you want achieve but in my opinion such logic should stay at database. Database engine has it own searching modules/queries wich not need to be developed again in your part of app. Still if you are going to have like 3000k requests per minute you may want to rework this sollution (postgreSQL is good idea with it but some orm would be needed then).